# Can mitmproxy log 'TLS Client Hello' & 'TLS Server Hello' messages?

Tags: ssl, mitmproxy

Mitmproxy logs the http and https requests and responses from a device that is under the proxy. Http/https is on the Application layer in the OSI model, I was wondering if mitmproxy can log 'TLS Client Hello' and 'TLS Server Hello' messages - is there an option? TLS is not in the application layer so I think it is not logged in any manner by mitmproxy. Can experts please confirm my understanding?

Comment: ClientHello and ServerHello are always in plaintext, would it be good enough for you to just record a PCAP?

Comment: When mitmproxy decrypts HTTPS traffic then it performs man-in-the-middle which means that it pretends to be the server for the client and for the server it pretends to be the client. Therefore it modifies TLS client and server hello which means it does not make sense to log them as they have been modified. If you want to log them disable mitmproxy and log them using Wireshark/tshark as Maximilian suggested.

Comment: Thank you Maximilian & Robert! Always appreciate your expert help. Yes, I can simply log them using pcap and it makes sense doing that without mitm - as the proxy modifies it as you rightly pointed out. I was looking for a way to track the client hello that originated from the proxy and the server hello that is received by the proxy (timings of these).